# поиск объекта в видеопотоке при помощи OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, видео

Имеется видеопоток, который снят со следующего ракурса:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Вопрос:** как при помощи opencv можно найти похожие объекты на столе?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть идея найти его при помощи цветовой сегментации, но не знаю как правильно задать hsv границы. Кто что может посоветовать в рамках данной задачи?

Comment: Что на счет свёрточных нейронных сетей (CNN)?

Comment: такой вариант не эффективный, слишком много ресурсов необходимо

Comment: Цветовой сегментации? Серъезно? У вас картинка в оттенках серого. Думаю надо задействовать детекторы и дескрипторы особых точек, типа SURF, ORB....